# grep report enclosing function name in context

Tags: function, grep, git-diff

git-diff reports the immediate function name that contains the change, like so:

```
$ git diff
diff --git a/apps/cli/elmo.py b/apps/cli/elmo.py
index ac056e9..1b7c1d0 100644
--- a/myfile.c
+++ b/myfile.c
@@ -100,12 +106,20 @@ int myioctl(unsigned int cmd, int size, int direction, unsigned long arg
                rc = myfunc1(ioargp);
                break;

-       case IOCTL_1:
-               rc = myfunc1(ioargp);
+       case IOCTL_2:
+               rc = myfunc2(arg);
                break;
```

Is there a way to make grep report the function context of the match, similar to git-diff (i.e., @@ int myioctl(...) in the above case)?  Or is there some replacement tool for grep that behaves like grep but will also report function context?

I often grep through source code, and it's helpful to know the function that contains the matched line without having to open the file and look for the specific pattern or line number.

Thanks!

Comment: see:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6133989/what-grep-command-will-include-the-current-function-name-in-its-output

Answer (score 2):

This is not exactly do-able, as I don't think you can represent all forms of function statements using regular expressions. You would need a grammar for that.

Anyway

So, you have the file names

Now you need to figure out the line numbers where the matching occurs.

```
grep -n "pattern" MYFILE | sed -r 's/([0-9]*):.*/\1/'
```

You want to know what function has the line printed above

```
grep -n "pattern" MYFILE | sed -r 's/([0-9]*):.*/\1/' | while read lineNo
do
    head -n $lineNo MYFILE | tac | egrep -m 1 "[[:alnum:]]+[[:space:]]+[[:alnum:]](.*)[[:space:]]*{"
done
```

This will give you the name of the function (hopefully) that contains the line where match occured.
*(I'm using **egrep** so I can use the **'+'** operator.)*

Note that this pattern matches a function declaration like so:

```
<function-type> <function-identifier> ( <things> ) {
```

You will need to extend it so it can represent more forms of function statements.

Comment: I don't necessarily have a diff or git output, because I am just grepping text (code) files.  I just supplied git-diff as an example of a tool that is aware of code context and supplies the function definition that contains the relevant "match". ...  Based on the above answer and the drought of other answers, I'm guessing I should read the git-diff source code and try to merge it into grep. ... :( ... Thanks for the suggestion.  :)

Comment: @Trevor Oh, I completely misunderstood the question. I thought you were using git-diff and it didn't supply you with function name, so you wanted to make it do so.

Comment: @Trevor Either way, you can have grep output the line numbers, and then continue with what I tried to provide you with. And let me know what you come up with. Sounds like a neat project idea.

Comment: @Trevor I fixed the answer so it matches your question. If you found your solution, just close this question so it doesn't keep poppin up in the 'unanswered' tab. Have a good day

Comment: Though the initial question was probably not meaning this, but I found this script useful for my case, Thanks! I did one modification to handle multiple files: `grep -n 'pattern' YOUR/FILES | sed -r 's/([a-z_/.]+):([0-9]*):.*/\2 \1/' | while read arg; do head -n $arg | tac |`...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the in-built [`git-grep`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-grep) which has an option to show context lines for the entire function:

> -W 
> --function-context 
> Show the surrounding text from the previous line containing a function name up to the one before the next function
> name, effectively showing the whole function in which the match was
> found. The function names are determined in the same way as git diff
> works out patch hunk headers (see Defining a custom hunk-header in
> [gitattributes[5]](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_defining_a_custom_hunk_header)).

Example: `git grep -W 'myioctl' -- path/to/myfile.c`